# How to use a result from a query with ORDER BY clause?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I want to order the result based on another query. Here's my query:

```
"SELECT * FROM red_table INNER JOIN blue_table ON red_table.ID = blue_table.ID";
```

I'd like to add `ORDER BY` using the result from another query:

```
"SELECT date FROM blue_table WHERE status = 'ready'";
```

So the final will be something like:

```
"SELECT * FROM red_table INNER JOIN blue_table ON red_table.ID = blue_table.ID ORDERY BY ( SELECT date FROM blue_table WHERE status = 'ready' )";
```

How do I do that? Or is it possible?

**UPDATE:**
I know I could just use `ORDER BY blue_table.date` but the `date` column contains values that are **not** Date. `blue_table` is kind of a metadata table. So I need to match the values from the `date` column with the `status` column so I only get the date values and use that for ordering. Maybe I shouldn't have called it column `date` but I hope you get my point.

Comment: You want to order by the date if status = ready?  What if it does not = ready?

Comment: `WHERE` doesn't imply any ordering whatsoever. Can you better explain what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Yeah. Well records with status != ready should be not be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you mean something like this? You would have to add additional column names in select

```
SELECT status, date 
  FROM red_table INNER JOIN blue_table ON red_table.ID = blue_table.ID 
   GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Comment: I updated my question, could you read it again please. Thanks!

Comment: Can you use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to create your schema and add some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM red_table 
INNER JOIN blue_table ON red_table.ID = blue_table.ID
WHERE blue_table.status = 'ready'
ORDER BY blue_table.date
```

Note that if `blue_table` does not contain a match for the join condition, nothing from `red_table` will be shown.